# Firebase storing data to wrong user ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, nosql

I'm trying to store data to a my `usersRef` in Firebase but it is being stored by the wrong key (userId).

After registering a new user, I give them a certain amount of *credits.*

```
addUser: function () {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.newuser.email, this.newuser.password).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // ...
        });
        console.log("adding user");
        try {
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;    
            var userRef = database.ref('users/' + user.uid + '/');
            userRef.set({'credits': this.newuser.credits});
            if (user){
                this.logInShow = false;
            }
        }
        catch(err){

        }
    },
```

Elsewhere users can deploy offers, which should be stored to the same userID as the credits.  However, a new userID is created and I am left with one userId that has a credits property and one that has an offer.

```
deployOffer: function(){
    try {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;    
        var userOffersRef = database.ref('users/' + user.uid + '/offers');
        offersRef.push(this.newoffer);
        userOffersRef.push(this.newoffer);
        this.offerShow = false;
        this.post = false;
    } catch (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
},
```

How could `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` be returning different keys when I've only registered one?  Here is what my db looks like after registering and then posting an offer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a race condition in your code. Creating a user takes time, so is an asynchronous operation. But you are immediate writing the initial credits for the user, which means that you are actually writing them to the previously signed in user (overwriting their existing credits and offers in the process).

The solution is to write the initial credits in the completion listener of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`:

```
addUser: function () {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      this.newuser.email, 
      this.newuser.password
    ).then(function(user) {
        console.log("adding user");
        var userRef = database.ref('users/' + user.uid + '/');
        userRef.set({'credits': this.newuser.credits});
        if (user){
            this.logInShow = false;
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // ...
    });
},
```